# codeigniter mysql stop third consecutive insert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this codeigniter mysql code to create an appointment:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
{
    $data = array(
        'startTime' => $startTime ,
        'endTime' => $endTime ,
        'day' => $date ,
        'contact_id' =>  $this->input->post('InputPatient') 
    );

    $this->db->insert('rdv', $data);
    echo 'Appointment Created Successfully.';
}
```

What I need is - for a specific time like 8pm, I should not have more than 2 appointment created. On third insert with same start time, I should give an error.

Thanks.

Comment: Check how many of them after the insert, and break the loop if needed.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Before you insert, check if there are already 2 appointments for a specific time and date.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
{
  $data = array(
     'startTime' => $startTime ,
     'endTime' => $endTime ,
     'day' => $date ,
     'contact_id' =>  $this->input->post('InputPatient') 
  );

  $isAlreadyTwo = $this->db->from("rdv")
                           ->where(array("startTime" => $startTime, "day" => $day))
                           ->count_all_results() >= 2;

  if($isAlreadyTwo)
  {
    echo "Error!!";
  }
  else
  {
    $this->db->insert('rdv', $data);
    echo 'Appointment Created Successfully.';
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Accepting the answer will give motivation to help more people like you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Before you do your `insert` you could do a `select` to see how many entries there are with the same start time.  If there are less than 2 then you can proceed to do your insert.

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as count')
    ->from('rdv')
    ->where('startTime', $startTime)
    ->where('day', $date);
$query = $this->db->get();

$aResult = $query->row_array();

if($aResult['count'] < 2)
{
    //Do your insert
}
```